# Tallit - to bless or not to bless?

Tags: sources-mekorot, blessing, tallit-gadol

My family has a *hanhagah* (practice) not to make a berachah on a tallit when putting the same beged on a second time in the same day. However, I’ve seen many others carefully make another berachah when doing so.

What are the sources for each of these practices ?

Comment: I've never heard of your practice. Can you elaborate on the parameters thereof? Is it only the same particular piece of clothing? Is there any rule about how long an interruption between is too much? What about erev Yom Kippur? I'm somewhat skeptical there is anything of value behind your practice,  depending on those answers of course

Comment: I think O.C. specifically mentions that once per day suffices. You may want to check beureihatefilah. Not sure, but he may have an article on this. B"N, I'll check tomorrow. If I'm not mistaken, Yekke chazzanim wear a tallit at mincha. Doesn't the chazzan make a bracha?

Comment: @DanF, it wouldn't be aloud, as it's not part of the seder hatefillot. I could ask at Breuer's, as I'll be there, this Shabbat.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I wear my nicer tallit on Y"K but my weekday one at shacharit that morning, so that's a non-issue. Be"H when I get married, I'll get a special tallit for R"H, Shabbat Shuvah, and Y"K

Comment: Are you willing to accept that there is no source for this practice of yours?

Comment: Have fun in my "old" neighborhood, and don't forget to do the special Breuer's Shabbat mincha shuffle when walking on Bennet Ave. going to shul. Can you clarify what you mean by "begged" and "tallit". I'm inferring that you mean specifically the same tallit gadol, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @DanF He could be talking of a tallis katan as well, no?

Comment: @ezra, there's a machloket regarding the recitation of a berachah for a tallit katan, regardless